# External 56Kbps dial-up USB modem

Tags: modem

I'm buying an external USB 56kbps dial-up modem. Does it have to be exactly the same brand, as the computer brand I have, which is a Dell? Or can I just buy any random external USB 56kbps dial-up modem and attach it to my Dell computer?

Answer (score 1):

For USB? No, not really. Any brand of modem would work with a dell.

While I *vaguely* recall a ['specialised' port for modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio/modem_riser) 56k modems were for most part entirely commodity components with nothing special about them.

Its worth remembering, while you're setting it up though, that dialup modems are *mostly* a relic of the past - and you might have trouble finding a service that works with it.

I would check for *explicit* driver compatibility for your version of windows as well.  US robotics, for example have a [compatibility matrix](http://www.usr.com/en-support/windows-compatibility/) for their modems - and this is the sort of thing I would look for in *picking out a modem*, especially on a more modern OS.

Comment: External 56k modems don't require drivers.  If it requires a driver its an internal Winmodem and probably should be avoided.

Comment: That's not strictly true. There's probably a generic driver somewhere. However considering they're legacy hardware I'd rather a modem the OEM confirms will work

Comment: You appear to be correct.  I just discovered you can get a USB Softmodem! That said, if the modem uses as serial interface however they all use versions of the HAYES AT standard which has been around since the 1980's and will work without any special drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any brand, although you need to realuse that, in real world connections you will not get 56k connections, and to get speeds above 33.6k requires the remote end has isdn based modems (rather then regular ones).

Not all modems are created equal either, but external modems will often be more reluable then cheap internal ones.

Comment: Oddly, I've never trusted USB devices of that rough era. I was *about* to suggest internal modems then I realised most of those were pretty crappy winmodems at the tail end of the dialup era.

Comment: Yup, give me a Rockwell chipset based serial modem any day. (USRobotics are cool too, but not as compatible).  Ive never used a USB modem though. That said, the X100P - a crappy winmodem - was, I believe what the most empowering modem as it broke the telco grip on high prices as it allowed Asterisk/Linux boxes to do VOIP -> landline cheaply.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be exactly the same brand as the brand of your computer. (To tell the truth, I've never heard of a Dell modem.)

But you are advised to purchase from a reputable manufacturer that offers a strong support policy.